# Highlight schedule in ListTile based on current time

Tags: flutter

i have this code but have no idea how to make the schedule highlighted based on current time. it can be card, box decoration or simply just shadow.

```js
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  String displaycode = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var futureBuilder = FutureBuilder<Tasks>(
          ...
          ...
            else
            return createListView(context, snapshot);
        }
      },
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: futureBuilder,
    );
  }

//ListTile times
  Widget createListView(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 20),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          _mainList("Math", Text(DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(DateFormat("HH:mm").parse(snapshot.data.task1)))),
          _mainList("English", Text(DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(DateFormat("HH:mm").parse(snapshot.data.task2)))),
          _mainList("History", Text(DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(DateFormat("HH:mm").parse(snapshot.data.task3)))),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
    
 _mainList(String name, clock){
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(name, textScaleFactor: 1.2),
        trailing: clock,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

for example if its 4:35pm, it should look like pic below, at 7:23pm the schedule "History" should be highlighted

[image]

thank you for your time, i really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  String displaycode = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var futureBuilder = FutureBuilder<Tasks>(
          ...
          ...
            else
            return createListView(context, snapshot);
        }
      },
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: futureBuilder,
    );
  }

//ListTile times
  Widget createListView(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 20),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          _mainList("Math", Text(DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(DateFormat("HH:mm").parse(snapshot.data.task1)))),
          _mainList("English", Text(DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(DateFormat("HH:mm").parse(snapshot.data.task2)))),
          _mainList("History", Text(DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(DateFormat("HH:mm").parse(snapshot.data.task3)))),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

 _mainList(String name, clock, bool isHighlighted){
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
      child: Container(
        color:isHighlighted?Colors.grey:Colors.transparent
        ListTile(
        title: Text(name, textScaleFactor: 1.2),
        trailing: clock,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am just going to leave your conditional logic right here for the sake of readability:

```
(DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(DateTime.parse(snapshot.data.task1)))==DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(DateTime.now()))?true:false;
```

Use this conditional logic to pass bool while you are calling _mainList.

Comment: the app wont work when i open in between the schedule time

Comment: How long is your schedule? You can just modify the code on the basis of that. Lets say you have an hour long schedule then you can just check datetime.now() isBetween the scheduled time and schedule period.